# Call child method class in parent with parent instance

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I don't want my parent class to be too long so I separate some methods from it and create child class.

However I don't want to use child class as a instance I want it to be used only by parent class.

```
class Parent {
  parentMethod() {
    this.foo(); // execute from parent
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {
  foo() {
    console.log('foo!');
  }
}

const parent = new Parent();
parent.parentMethod(); // execute parent method which execute child method
```

this cause:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.foo is not a function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't want my parent class to be too long so I separate some methods from it

Ok.

> So I create child class, however I don't want to use child class as a instance.

No, subclassing is the wrong approach here. Especially if you don't want to instantiate the subclass, it's not even a solution to your problem.

To separate units of code, factor them out into separate functions. Those don't need to be linked to the caller through inheritance, and don't need to be methods of a class at all. Just write

```
class MyClass {
  myMethod() {
    foo();
  }
}

function foo() {
  console.log('foo!');
}

const instance = new MyClass();
instance.myMethod();
```

Or compose your object of multiple smaller helpers:

```
class Outer {
  constructor() {
    this.helper = new Inner();
  }
  myMethod() {
    this.helper.foo();
  }
}

class Inner {
  foo() {
    console.log('foo!');
  }
}

const instance = new Outer();
instance.myMethod();
```

Comment: Yes but I have 20 functions like foo and every is related to one thing so I thought that I could wrap them in class but I could also wrap them in object and export object (this is server side js). Am I right? I want nice architecture and I don't want much in global scope

Comment: @BT101 On the server side, you are working with modules anyway, so the functions are in a local scope. Use named exports for ES6 modules for example, not need to put them in an object literal - although you can of course do that.

Comment: @BT101 And if you have 20 functions that deal with related things, you might consider putting them in a class and apply [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to use them in your other class. The outer-scope function was just the simplest solution for the code that you've shown in the question.

Comment: Could you also provide some simple example of composition with my Parent and Child classes in your answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `Parent` class in the subclass, `Child` class, then you need to do the following:

```
class Parent {
    foo() {
        console.log('foo!');
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

let c = new Child(); //instantiate Child class
c.foo(); // here you are calling super.foo(); which is the Parent classes method for foo.
//foo!
```

> The super keyword is used to access and call functions on an object's
>   parent.

[How to use super](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super#Description)

Or, alternatively, if you'd rather create a method on the child class that wraps the parent method of foo, rather than accessing it by instantiating the parent class via calling `super` in the child constructor:

```
class Parent {
    foo() {
        console.log('foo!');
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {
    method() {
        this.foo();
    }
}

let c = new Child();
c.method();
```

Comment: This makes no sense, please change the names so that the child class is called `Child` and the parent class is called `Parent`.

Comment: @Bergi You're right, I copied the original question but didn't change the names around. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The child class need not to have a constructor, but it should have the method that calls `this.foo`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as OP `didn't want to use a child class as an instance`.